# Make components draggable in edit pan

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf

I created drag and drop based dynamic components like button etc. But in the drop area what are the components i created that should be draggable for alignment like dotnet form component aligning. Give some ideas...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [jQuery UI Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/).

Comment: i tried based on that i created drag and drop but in the drop div i m creating n components n components should be draggable

Comment: Then have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13442849/1846192